# Sublimelinter (PC): How to trigger this shortcut ("Lint This View"): Ctrl K, l?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I am trying to figure out how you use this shortcut, but I am having trouble.
What does it mean by "Ctrl K, l"?

I have tried various combinations but in vain.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the default config file: [Default (Windows).sublime-keymap](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3/blob/master/Default%20%28Windows%29.sublime-keymap)

And here is the string which creates this shortcut:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "l"], "command": "sublimelinter_lint" },
```

That means you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and then press <kbd>l</kbd>. It's a sequence key bind that you're allowed to make in your custom keymap file as well.

Make sure to have <kbd>ctrl</kbd> released while pressing <kbd>l</kbd>.

---

P.S. it's a small `L` and not capital `i`. How do I know? I copy pasted it to sublime text, selected and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

This is a default keymap: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+u"], "command": "upper_case" },`

Comment: I will test it out later and tell you if that works on my machine (: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation.

Comment: @Vennsoh hope it does!